# How to find two functions are measurable or not?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E$ be a non measurable subset of $(0,1)$. Define two functions as follows:

$f_1(x)=1/x$  if $x∈E$ and $0$ if $x∉E$               and

$f_2(x)=0$  if $x∈E $ and $f(x)=1/x$    if $x∉E$

then  are $f_1$ and $f_2$ measurable ?

Comment: Please learn to use MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It makes it much easier to read your problem.

Comment: I have changed the awful mess you had given into a readable text. Next time, to begin with, enclose mathematical formulas between dollar signs  and learn MathJax.

Comment: You should give your own attempt on the problem, before you can expect us to help you.  To start: what is the definition of measurable function?  What happens when you try to apply it to $f_1$?

Comment: By definition, an extended real valued function f is said to be Lebesgue measurable if its domain is measurable and for each real α the set {x: f(x) < α } is measurable.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

What about the sets $\{x\in(0,1)\colon f_1(x)>0\}$ and $\{x\in(0,1)\colon f_2(x)=0\}$? Read about equivalent conditions of measurability.

Another, more theoretical approach: $f_1(x)=\frac{1}{x}\chi_E(x)$. The set is measurable iff its characteristic function is measurable. Similar argument could be applied for $f_2$.